# urlopen error during Facebook posts scraping

Tags: web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm using scraper from this [repo](https://github.com/minimaxir/facebook-page-post-scraper) to crawl posts of [the Facebook Homepage of ChinaEUMission](https://www.facebook.com/ChinaEUMission/?ref=br_rs). I fill my App ID and App Secret as instructed, and fill 'ChinaEUMission' as page_id. However, there is always error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
Error for URL https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/355117227946201_512441325547123/?fields
=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).       
summary(total_count).as(love),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0). summary(total_count).as(wow),
reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(haha),reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).
summary(total_count).as(sad),reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(angry)&
access_token=*******
```